# Html adding rows to table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

how do i add a new row on top of the old row? when i press the button first it adds fine but then when i try to add a new row it adds on the right side andi am really confused can you guys help me out?(sorry for my bad english and thanks in advance!)

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("div").hover(function(){
        $(this).fadeTo("fast",1);
        }, function(){
        $(this).fadeTo("fast",0.5);
        });
    
    $("#BTN_AddToWebsites").click(function(){
    
    var site = $('#INPUT_NameOfTheSite').val();
    var url = $('#INPUT_TheSitesUrl').val();
    var domain = $('#INPUT_Domain').val();
    
    
    if(site.length >= 1 && url.length >= 1 && domain.length >= 1){
        /*Text to appear*/
      $('.SiteSection').after('<td class="textfix">'+"https://www."+url+domain+'</td>');
      $('.SiteSection').after('<td class="textfix">'+site+'</td>');
      
      $('#INPUT_NameOfTheSite').val('');
      $('#INPUT_TheSitesUrl').val('');
      $('#INPUT_Domain').val('');
      
      $("#INPUT_NameOfTheSite").css("border", "2px solid black");
      $("#INPUT_TheSitesUrl").css("border", "2px solid black");
      $("#INPUT_Domain").css("border", "2px solid black");
      
    }
    
    if(site.length === 0){
       $("#INPUT_NameOfTheSite").css("border", "2px solid red");
    }
    
     if(url.length === 0){
      $("#INPUT_TheSitesUrl").css("border", "2px solid red");
    }
    
     if(domain.length === 0){
      $("#INPUT_Domain").css("border", "2px solid red");
    }
    
    });
    
      $("#INPUT_NameOfTheSite").click(function(){
       $("#INPUT_NameOfTheSite").css("border", "2px solid black");
      });
       $("#INPUT_TheSitesUrl").click(function(){
       $("#INPUT_TheSitesUrl").css("border", "2px solid black");
      });
       $("#INPUT_Domain").click(function(){
       $("#INPUT_Domain").css("border", "2px solid black");
      });
      
    });
```

Comment: An example of your html would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine that your call to add your new element on '.siteSection' is targeting the first element of that class and adding it at that point rather than the last one.

Try using a ':last' pseudo selector after your siteSelection class like $('.siteSelection:last')

Working Change: addition of the table row was missing from the addition function. Changed in https://jsfiddle.net/6uryyruv/2/ to reflect this.

Approx Line: 17:

```
$('.SiteSection:last').after('<tr class="SiteSection"><td class="textfix">'+site+'</td><td class="textfix">'+"https://www."+url+domain+'</td>tr>');
```

I'd prefer to update it a little more so its a 'nicer' block of code and easier to read - but that should be your fix for this particular issue.

Comment: thanks for the replay but i tried it and it still keeps adding to the right side here have a look at the html css and jquery here https://jsfiddle.net/6uryyruv/ add two websites and you will see that it adds to the right side not on top! sorry for any bad spelling!

Comment: Doh - should have seen this earlier but guess tired eyes came into account.

You were adding a TD (column) to the end of your 'SiteSection' rather than a TR (row).

Change the line that is directly under /* Text To Appear */ to the following:

$('.SiteSection:last').after('<tr class="SiteSection"><td class="textfix">'+site+'</td><td class="textfix">'+"https://www."+url+domain+'</td>tr>');

I've updated the fiddle also: https://jsfiddle.net/6uryyruv/2/ (I'll try and update it a little more later on so that the code is a bit cleaner but I've got to get to work for now.

Hope it helped.

Comment: this one worked $('.SiteSection:last').after('<tr class="SiteSection"><td class="textfix">'+site+'</td><td class="textfix">'+"https://www."+url+domain+'</td>tr>'); thanks for the help!